# Cannot load image in a browser from external hdd

Tags: hard-drive, image

I have an external HDD connected to a Raspberry. I can read and write to the hdd, but when i create a simple tag in html, it does not load the image:

> `<img src=/mnt/hdd/image.jpg />`

The image is 644 and owned/grouped by www-data. I run a php script contains a html tag img. If I modify the path of the image file to 'image.jpg' , it successfully loads from the default /var/www/html folder what is the documentroot. But if I copy that image to /mnt/hdd it fails loading it. How can I address that file?

What am I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: You need to have images in a location that can be served up by your webserver. You can't just you an arbitrary path like that as its resolved by the viewer of the page to whom that path is doesn't mean anything to. If you are just opening your webpage directly you should be able to view images at the same folder level by using the `src` as `src=''/image.jpg` - note some browsers restrict loading resources like this

Comment: A coupla' comments: 1) As you've described it, this is NOT a Raspberry Pi issue per se (yeah, I know it is in your case, but in general, no - it is not)  2) You've not given enough details for anyone to answer the question. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), do your homework, and try again please.

Comment: @tobyd: yes, of course, i was not clear enough in the question: i run a php script contains a html tag img. If I modify the path of the image file to 'image.jpg' , it successfully loads from the default /var/www/html folder what is the documentroot. But if i copy that image to /mnt/hdd it fails loading it. How can I address that file?

Comment: If you symlink (shortcut) the `hdd` image to via `sudo ln -s /mnt/hdd/image.jpg /var/www/html/image.jpg` then use `src='/image.jpg'` you might find that works - thats a guess though, I don't know if your webserver will follow symlinks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works perfectly. 
I also considered extending the DocumentRoot, but this solution is much easier.